# Como rodar um subprocess com permissão de administrador?

Tags: python, windows, sistema-operacional, cmd

Eu estou fazendo um script que acessa o `cmd` do Windows, via `subprocess`. Só que eu preciso rodar o `cmd` como administrador.

A solução que eu encontrei, não me satisfaz, que seria utilizar o `runas`. O que eu quero saber é se existe algum meio de adquirir **status de administrador** dentro do script, sem precisar **executar como administrador**. Existe alguma forma?

Comment: Acho difícil. Em teoria isso é impossível para segurança.

Comment: Então, não sei, seria algo equivalente ao `sudo` do linux.

Comment: Se você agendar uma tarefa com credenciais de administrador, pode permitir qualquer usuário executá-la com privilégios elevados sem precisar de senha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de algum tempo buscando na internet, achei no SOEN [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719292/1606920) que faz basicamente o que eu quero.

Ela fala de um script criado por Preston Landers, que executa o `runas`, proposto pelo @utluiz dentro do próprio [python](/questions/tagged/python). Segue código do módulo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: python; py-indent-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*-
# vim: fileencoding=utf-8 tabstop=4 expandtab shiftwidth=4

# (C) COPYRIGHT © Preston Landers 2010
# Released under the same license as Python 2.6.5


import sys, os, traceback, types

def isUserAdmin():

    if os.name == 'nt':
        import ctypes
        # WARNING: requires Windows XP SP2 or higher!
        try:
            return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print "Admin check failed, assuming not an admin."
            return False
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        # Check for root on Posix
        return os.getuid() == 0
    else:
        raise RuntimeError, "Unsupported operating system for this module: %s" % (os.name,)

def runAsAdmin(cmdLine=None, wait=True):

    if os.name != 'nt':
        raise RuntimeError, "This function is only implemented on Windows."

    import win32api, win32con, win32event, win32process
    from win32com.shell.shell import ShellExecuteEx
    from win32com.shell import shellcon

    python_exe = sys.executable

    if cmdLine is None:
        cmdLine = [python_exe] + sys.argv
    elif type(cmdLine) not in (types.TupleType,types.ListType):
        raise ValueError, "cmdLine is not a sequence."
    cmd = '"%s"' % (cmdLine[0],)
    # XXX TODO: isn't there a function or something we can call to massage command line params?
    params = " ".join(['"%s"' % (x,) for x in cmdLine[1:]])
    cmdDir = ''
    showCmd = win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL
    #showCmd = win32con.SW_HIDE
    lpVerb = 'runas'  # causes UAC elevation prompt.

    # print "Running", cmd, params

    # ShellExecute() doesn't seem to allow us to fetch the PID or handle
    # of the process, so we can't get anything useful from it. Therefore
    # the more complex ShellExecuteEx() must be used.

    # procHandle = win32api.ShellExecute(0, lpVerb, cmd, params, cmdDir, showCmd)

    procInfo = ShellExecuteEx(nShow=showCmd,
                              fMask=shellcon.SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS,
                              lpVerb=lpVerb,
                              lpFile=cmd,
                              lpParameters=params)

    if wait:
        procHandle = procInfo['hProcess']    
        obj = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(procHandle, win32event.INFINITE)
        rc = win32process.GetExitCodeProcess(procHandle)
        #print "Process handle %s returned code %s" % (procHandle, rc)
    else:
        rc = None

    return rc

def test():
    rc = 0
    if not isUserAdmin():
        print "You're not an admin.", os.getpid(), "params: ", sys.argv
        #rc = runAsAdmin(["c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"])
        rc = runAsAdmin()
    else:
        print "You are an admin!", os.getpid(), "params: ", sys.argv
        rc = 0
    x = raw_input('Press Enter to exit.')
    return rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(test())
```

Vale ressaltar que esse script só vale para **Windows XP SP 2** ou **superior**.

Comment: Abordagem interessante!

Answer (score 1):

O Windows possui um comando chamado `runas`. Digitando esse comando sem parâmetros no `cmd` do Windows XP, obtenho a seguinte ajuda:

```
RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/netonly] ]
        /user:<UserName> program

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/netonly] ]
        /smartcard [/user:<UserName>] program

   /noprofile        specifies that the user's profile should not be loaded.
                     This causes the application to load more quickly, but
                     can cause some applications to malfunction.
   /profile          specifies that the user's profile should be loaded.
                     This is the default.
   /env              to use current environment instead of user's.
   /netonly          use if the credentials specified are for remote
                     access only.
   /savecred         to use credentials previously saved by the user.
                     This option is not available on Windows XP Home Edition
                     and will be ignored.
   /smartcard        use if the credentials are to be supplied from a
                     smartcard.
   /user             <UserName> should be in form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER
   program         command line for EXE.  See below for examples

Examples:
> runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
> runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""

NOTE:  Enter user's password only when prompted.
NOTE:  USER@DOMAIN is not compatible with /netonly.
NOTE:  /profile is not compatible with /netonly.
```

Portanto, creio que você poderia executar o seguinte comando a partir do Python:

```
runas /profile /user:<domínio>\<administrador> "cmd ..."
```

Sendo:

- `<domínio>` o nome do domínio ou o nome da máquina local; e
- `<administrador>` o nome do usuário com privilégios administrativos.

Note que será exigido que o usuário informe as credenciais do usuário administrador. Porém, isso pode ser mitigado com a opção `/savecred`, a qual utiliza credenciais salvas anteriormente. Mas você precisa verificar se sua versão do Windows suporta a opção.

Comment: Isso seria pra eu rodar abrir um `cmd` como administrador, não pra ganhar "status" de administrador. Isso é equivalente ao clicar com botão direito e executar como administrador.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar A solução para "Rodar o `cmd` como administrador" e esta, não dá pra burlar autenticação do Sistema Operacional. Pesquisei um pouco mais e encontrei [essa questão no SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script). Dá uma olhada nas duas primeiras respostas.

Comment: mas esse comando é pra abrir um outro `cmd` com privilégio, eu queria dar os privilégios pro subprocess do Python. Eu sei que é possível dá pra fazer a partir [dessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file), mas eu queria tipo um `sudo`, já que eu não sei como aplicar isso no Python. :/

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Pelo que dizem não dá pra fazer isso. Eu pelo menos não tenho ideia de outras alternativas. Sorry...